# iPhone accessibility on button with image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, button, accessibility

Anyone knows how to prevent VoiceOver from speaking the button image filename?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.button.accessibilityLabel = @"Your accessibility label";
self.button.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

If you set an accessible name for the button, Voiceover will read that instead of the filename. find exact info at http://developer.apple.com/accessibility

Comment: Im not at home right now but ill test it again, ive setted the hint for the button but the image filename was read by the accessibility voiceover... What accessibility propertie you've setted? Thanks for the reply